How to create a macro to automatically create (or update) PDF with preserved links?
I have tried to create a macro to create a PDF from my excel workbook. One sheet on the workbook has links for the other sheets. I would like to create the macro to either create (or ideally automatically update) a PDF document for me, so that I can then send the link to others. I've copied this macro from elsewhere, but it creates a new PDF with links that do not work.
Sub SaveActiveWorkbookAsPDF()

'Create and assign variables
Dim saveLocation As String
saveLocation = "C:\Users\User\OneDrive - file location\TestPDF.pdf"

'Save active workbook as PDF
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=saveLocation

End Sub

I was hoping to start by saving a PDF that has intact links.

Thank you for reformatting. Would anyone be able to help preserve links?

Try looking at How to keep all hyperlinks working when exporting my workbook as pdf file?
